# Is it possible to detect when Bluetooth is turned off until tomorrow (white button in command centre) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

How can I detect that bluetooth is turned off until tomorrow. In bluetooth delegate there is only turned off or turned on? And when it is turned off until tomorrow it is turned off in delegate

Comment: "Turned off until tomorrow" prevents discovery of new devices, so for the purposes of an app using Core Bluetooth that is "off"